# Checkedlistbox checkboxes are "standard" style, I want flatstyle?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

As the question denotes, I have some "flatstyle" buttons and checked boxes. The only item I seem unable to change to flat style is a checkedlistbox, this makes the checkedlistbox look out of place on the form.

I have searched around and only come up with ThreeDCheckboxes which visibly does nothing?

Any information regarding this would be greatfully received

Cheers

Comment: "Flat" controls are long-deprecated. They have been drawn the same as 3D controls ever since the introduction of Visual Styles (Windows XP). The WinForms framework has to simulate it by owner-drawing. The result is ugly, and inconsistent with the standard platform UI. The best solution is to set *all* controls' `FlatStyle` property to `System`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might solve your problem. On form load you can disable visual styles for the entire form.

```
private void frm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.VisualStyleState = VisualStyleState.NoneEnabled;
    this.Invalidate();
}
```

Will this work for you?

Comment: Then it is easier delete the line `Application.EnableVisualStyles();` in Program.cs file.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Yes you are right. If not by disabling the VisualStyles then I don't see any other way.

Comment: There is no other way. I explain the reason why in my comment above. When Visual Styles are enabled, all checkboxes get drawn by the system in exactly the same way. There is no longer any distinction between "flat" and "3D" controls. The only other thing you could do would be to completely owner-draw the checkbox. Which, for a CheckedListBox, would mean owner-drawing the entire listbox and implementing the checking/unchecking logic yourself. Strongly discouraged, your implementation will inevitably be buggy. I see no compelling reason to insist your controls are ugly and look different anyway.

Comment: This kind of worked, will just leave it as it is however as it messes with everything on the form! 

@codyGray Thank you for your comment, I'm rather new to C# (Programming in general, dabbled in VB a few years back) I didn't realise Flat Styles were out-dated, they changed on the win forms and seem cleaner than the standard button and checkbox on Win7, hence why I wanted it to be the same in the checkedlistbox

Comment: I'm not really sure how you can get "cleaner" than "what every other application, including the Windows shell uses." Anyway, flat controls were introduced some time in the late 1990s by either the Microsoft Money or Microsoft Encarta/Bookshelf teams. They appeared in both products relatively simultaneously, a byproduct of the fact that Microsoft's favorite thing to reinvent is the common controls. Other vendors then try to follow suit, with poor and buggy implementations. It's all rather silly. Making your application look different for the sake of it has negative value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CheckBox ComboBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21085/CheckBox-ComboBox-Extending-the-ComboBox-Class-and) component. Not a listview but implement FlatStyle and offer similar behaviour if you have not much items.